# FlatBuffer unable to generate .bin file

Tags: android, flatbuffers

I am using [FlatBuffer 1.8 release](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/releases) (windows `flatc`)

Here are few commands which i have tried in cmd windows.

```
 C:\>C:\Flat\flatc.exe flatbuffer -b -j "C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\src\main\res\raw\sample_schema.fbs"  "C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\src\main\res\raw\sample_json.json"
```

one more using flatbuffer jar file

```
  C:\>C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\libs>flatbuffers-java-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar flatc C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\src\main\res\raw\job_schema.fbs C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\src\main\res\raw\job.json
```

which gives me following error

[image]

**sample_schema.fbs & sample_json.json** is available [on this link](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/FlatBuffer/tree/master/app/src/main/res/raw)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your error doesn't contain the actual error message.. it is usually the first thing printed. Also, flatc doesn't use a .jar.

Answer (score 0):

Your command includes the word `flatbuffer`, which does not fit the specification of the command:

> flatc.exe [OPTION]... FILE... [-- FILE...]

To fix the command, remove that word:

> C:>C:\Flat\flatc.exe -b -j "C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\src\main\res\raw\sample_schema.fbs" "C:\Akash\FlatBuffer\app\src\main\res\raw\sample_json.json"

With this example, three files should be created: `Friend.java`, `People.java`, `PeopleList.java`, and `sample_json.bin`.

Comment: It gives me following error in cmd `C:\Flat\flatc.exe: error: Unable to generate Java for sample_schema`
`Usage: C:\Flat\flatc.exe [OPTION]... FILE... [-- FILE...]` and .bin file and java files are not generating

Comment: here is sample https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/FlatBuffer please delete `.bin` and '`flatbuffer java` classes then run your command. it will not generate bin files and java files.